# In R, how to collapse (sum) the tail end of an ordered dataframe into "n or more"?

Tags: r, dplyr

**Background**

I've got a dataframe `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(count_events = c(0,1,2,3),
                count_people = c(123,56,2,8),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  

> d
  count_events count_people
1            0          123
2            1           56
3            2            2
4            3            8
```

**The problem**

I'd like a way to collapse rows 3 and 4 of `d` into one row that says something like "2 or more" in `count_events` and sums 2 and 8 into 10 for `count_people`. So in other words something like this:

```
> d
  count_events count_people
1            0          123
2            1           56
3          >=2            10
```

**What I've tried**

I can do what I want with `rbind`, like so:

```
d <- d[-c(3:4),]
new_row <- c('2 or more', 10)
d <- rbind(d, new_row)

> d
  count_events count_people
1            0          123
2            1           56
3    2 or more           10
```

But I'm wondering if there's something faster or more elegant. The "real" dataframe I'm trying to do this on has many rows, and many rows I'd like to collapse. It's doable, but it'll take me a decent chunk of time and I thought to myself "is there a dedicated function for something like this?". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

d |> 
  mutate(count_events = ifelse(row_number() >= 3, "2 or more", count_events)) |> 
  count(count_events, wt = count_people)
#>   count_events   n
#> 1            0 123
#> 2            1  56
#> 3    2 or more  10
```

Answer (score 1):

data.table equivalent to stefan's answer

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, .(count_people = sum(count_people)),
  keyby = .(count_events =
    fifelse(count_events >= 2, "2 or more", as.character(count_events)))]

# count_events count_people
# 1:            0          123
# 2:            1           56
# 3:    2 or more           10
```